# Text Inside SVG Circle in D3 Doesn't Show

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, text

I am trying to append text inside `SVG` circles like  [this](http://bl.ocks.org/ChrisJamesC/4474971) example in my `D3` map. I've seen a lot of similiar questions posted on SO - and I've used them to write the code below, but do not understand why it doesn't show up at all.

```
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3.github.com/master/world-110m.v1.json", function (error, topo) {
            if (error) throw error;

            gBackground.append("g")
                .attr("id", "country")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.countries).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path);


            gBackground.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(topo, topo.objects.countries, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("id", "country-borders")
                .attr("d", path);


            console.log("Background Drawn");

           var point = gPoints.selectAll("circle")
                .data(pointsData)     
                .enter()            
                .append("circle")    
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.location[0]; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.location[1]; })
                .attr("r", 10)
                //Other attributes and mouseovers, etc


           var texts = gPoints.selectAll("text")
               .data(pointsData)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function (d) { return d.performance; });

            console.log("Points Drawn");

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `text` is not coming up is because: you have not specified any location where it need to come up.

For circles you are giving a `cx` and `cy` but nothing for the text.

A better approach would be to make a group like this:

```
var elem = gPoints.selectAll("g .myCircleText").data(pointsData)
/*Create and place the "blocks" containing the circle and the text */  
var elemEnter = elem.enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("myCircleText", true) //add a class to the group
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.location[0]+","+ d.location[1]+")"})
```

Give the group a translate as shown above(so that you don't need to give a cx and cy the group is translated to the required point).

Now make circles inside the group like this:

```
/*Create the circle for each block */
var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10 )
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("fill", "white")
```

Now make text inside the group

```
/* Create the text for each block */
elemEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d){return -20})//so that it comes 20 pixel from center.
    .text(function(d){return d.performance})
```